# Crossfilter and Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, crossfilter

How to implement a crossfilter with Highcharts ? I know that in D3 it is possible but in Highcharts ?

**Question to Highchart Team:** When I will buy a license having yours support can I get answer to my question ?

Comment: Your main questions seems to be answer by Sigfried. About license: see [Highcharts support site](http://www.highcharts.com/support) to learn more about license and support. Other useful link - [FAQ](https://shop.highsoft.com/faq#Support-0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossfilter is just about controlling data. If you use Crossfilter and then hand off data to Highcharts in the format Highcharts expects, you should be fine.

Comment: Do you have any proof of concept ? I was looking for quite a lot but unsuccessfully ?

Comment: You've probably moved on by now, but I would say if you could provide a short bit of code showing how you're trying to use crossfilter and what data you'd like to pass to highcharts, I could fill in the missing pieces. If I did make a proof of concept, it likely wouldn't cover your use case anyway.